# how to make a responsive 5 stars with D3

Tags: html, d3.js, flask

I'm trying to build a D3/Flask app. I have a text box in which I can input review for some particular product.My model will predict the implied rating from the review text.  What I need is five yellow stars above my text box, just like those on amazon. I want to make it responsive according to the rating predicted from text. Greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: Please, show some code, any code. At least the code for painting the text, the stars (all gray) and the data related to it, then we just deal with colouring the stars. Otherwise, it seems that you are just asking people to write code for you, for free.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado   I'm new to D3. I have no idea how to make those five stars line up each other.  Is there any D3 component like the slidebar, etc. Any resource info is welcome. I'm not trying to have people write code for me. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: No worries. However, unfortunately, as you're looking for a tutorial, Stack Overflow is not the adequate site for you.

Comment: You can probably achieve the desired effect much more easily with a set of images (e.g. 5 different "states" of a star) and some simple javascript. If you want to use D3...write a function to draw 1 star of a set size at a set of coordinates, then repeat it 5 times. Start with drawing a line. A star is 10 lines. D3 is not the choice if you want fully baked solutions handed to you.